# Finding a File within Filesystem

Tags: java

Good Evening,

I'm trying to find a file which exists within my own project filesystem and I am not sure how to do so...

```
 File dir = new File(Filename);
```

will only help me find files in my computer's directories.

Is there an option to do this, with or without an additional library?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Finding a file using a full URL is also a viable solution to my problem.

Comment: Your filesystem is your computer's directories though? Maybe I misunderstood, but what is the issue with using `File`?

Comment: I meant the project file system, sorry

Comment: This is a valid question, File dir = new File(Filename); will not help you find files within a project filesystem aka using incomplete directories. I'm not sure why I'm getting downvotes

Comment: You could use [`ClassLoader#getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) like `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good evening,

`getClass().getResource("lib/txtfile.txt")` this gives file txtfile.txt, you can work arround with it to get absolute path of your project something like `getClass().getResource("/")`

I think this will help you to get root folder of your project, then you can search inside to find your file.

Comment: or something similar to `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();`

Answer (score 0):

if u want to search in particular directory/location, u need to pass abstract path in constructor (e.g. c:/abc/mydir/)

or if you want to 'search' for files in all available paths in ur pc, 1st u need to get list of available drives

```
File[] roots = File.listRoots();
```

then you can write a recursive routine to iterate over all directories and list all files in it.